# Android reinstall the same program

Tags: android

I would like to update my program. So when it start the program I check if any available updates. If it does then download and try to install with these:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "own.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(intent);
```

The program is reach the install dialog but when click it the program shutdown. I think  cause i reinstall with the same program. Which is the solutions for reinstall or changed to the new updates?

Comment: **The program is reach the install dialog but when click it the program shutdown. I think cause i reinstall with the same program. Which is the solutions for reinstall or changed to the new updates?** what does it means - are you saying that your programme get closed when you call for the update code? are you calling `finish()` any where in the same code ?

Comment: Yes when I reached to install party and I clicked it just quite from the program and do not restart with the new updates. Or maybe am I wrong it is updates just not start?

Answer (score 3):

Don't ruin the pattern that Android costructed.
if there is an available update and the user wants to update just send them to Google Play.

Comment: But I have to use external server!

Answer (score 0):

> I think cause i reinstall with the same program.

Correct. Android needs to terminate your process as part of that.

> Which is the solutions for reinstall or changed to the new updates?

The user can launch your app again manually.

Or, you can try registering a `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` receiver in the manifest, and take steps if it is yours.

Comment: Could you show me some example to the ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED function?

Comment: @meklod400: Sorry, I do not have such an example handy.